# Why can I conclude $A=\overline{A}{}^{\intercal}$

Tags: linear-algebra

**My problem:**

Suppose $A \in \mathscr{M}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is such that for all $z \in \mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}$:

$$z^TA \mbox{ }\overline{z} > 0$$

Can I conclude $A=\overline{A}{}^{\intercal}$?

**My attempt:**

I would like to prove that $A$ necessarly represent an Hermitian product but I am not able to do it.

Comment: @user You are right, I will add it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you saying that the above quantity is real for all $z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily, take:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}10 & 1 \\ 0 & 10\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini how does the edit invalidate my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Any matrix $A$ which is $A=B+C$ with $B$ positive-definite hermitian and $C$ *skew*-hermitian will have the posited property: certainly $z^\top B \overline{z}>0$ (for non-zero $z$), and a direct computation shows that $z^\top C\overline{z}=0$ for all vectors $z$.